# Compose list of functions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, fold, function-composition

I need to define a function that receives a tuple **t1** `(String,(Int,Int,Int)` and another tuple **t2** `(String,[(String,Int,[Fs])])`. It has to return the tuple **t1** with modified values in its second element `(Int,Int,Int)`. This alterations are caused by the functions stored in the tuple **t2**.

If I'm correct, first I need to generate a list of functions from the second tuple, which I did with fold:

```
trd3 (a,b,c) = c
listFunctions = foldr (++) [] (map trd3 (snd t2))
```

The problem appears when I want to use fold again to compose the list of functions, that it's not working:

```
foldr (.) (snd t1) (foldr (++) [] (map trd3 (snd t2)))
```

As an example, I could say that

```
t1 = ("Warrior",(15,5,12))
t2 = ("Bag",[("HP potion",5,[f1,f2]),("MP potion",3,[f3])])
f1 (a,b,c) = (a+10,b+5,c)
f2 (a,b,c) = (a+5,b+5,c)
f3 (a,b,c) = (a,b+5,c+15)
```

So the function should return something like `(f3 . f2 . f1) (15,5,12)`

I have also seen this link: http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Compose but can't understand it 100%.

If someone could explain how to work this out, that would be really appreciated.

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: What are you want to achieve? It could be much easier for us to help you if you clearly state what you want to achieve first, then show us your problematic implementation.

Comment: Think about the types of your compositing function and base case in your second fold. You're composing a list of functions with `foldr (.) (snd t1) listFunctions`, that doesn't evaluate to `(f3 . f2 . f1) (snd t1)` like you want it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is where you put the `snd t1`.

```
foldr (.) (snd t1) (foldr (++) [] (map trd3 (snd t2)))
```

Let's pretend for a moment that this type checked, then this would evaluate to

```
f3 . f2 . f1 . snd t1
```

which is nonsense because `snd t1` isn't a function, so you can't compose it.

What you want to do is to first compose the functions, then *apply* the resulting function to `snd t1`. You can do this by using `id` as the second argument to `foldr`, i.e.

```
foldr (.) id (foldr (++) [] (map trd3 (snd t2))) $ snd t1
```

which evaluates to

```
f3 . f2 . f1 . id $ snd t1
```

which is of course the same as

```
f3 . f2 . f1 $ snd t1
```

which is what you wanted.

Comment: It worked! Can you explain what is `id` and what you did with `$ snd t1`, please? Thank you very much!

Comment: @warty: `id` is the identity function, defined as `id x = x`, so in a sense it "does nothing". `$` is an operator which does function application, defined as `f $ x = f x`. It has a very low precedence, so it's often used instead of parentheses. For example, `f3 . f2 . f1 $ snd t1` is the same as `(f3 . f2 . f1) (snd t1)`.

Comment: Got it, thank you. Was checking and seems the composition is being created backwards (f1 . f2 . f3), f3 being applied first and f1 last.
I think I will reverse the list before composing. For some reason foldr and foldl aren't making any difference.

Comment: Just one more doubt, why is that in your foldr you use 4 arguments instead of the 3 that fold requires? Thanks.

Comment: @warty: The first three arguments go to `foldr`. Since we're composing functions, the result of the `foldr` is a function. That function receives the final argument. Function application associates to the left, so `(f x) y` is the same as `f x y`, and similarly `(foldr f z xs) y` is the same as `foldr f z xs y`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but you can compose a list of `a -> a` (endofunctions) using Foldable and the `Endo` Monoid:

```
-- Given some listOfFunctions :: [a -> a] and initialValue :: a, for some type a:
appEndo (foldMap Endo listOfFunctions) initialValue
```

For example:

```
λ> import Data.Foldable (foldMap)
λ> import Data.Monoid
λ> appEndo (foldMap Endo [(+2), (*10), (/2)]) 50  -- This evaluates ((50/2)*10)+2
252.0
```